Connectedness of Space of Caccioppoli Sets?
Let $(M^n, g)$ a closed, connected riemannian manifold. Is the space of all caccioppoli sets on $M$ connected with respect to the flat norm? How about with respect to the F norm (Flat metric on the caccioppoli sets + varifold metric on the boundaries)?
How about path-connected instead of connected? Or for fixed-volume caccioppoli sets? Any references or insights would be very useful, as I'm struggling to find prior work on this. Thanks!

How do you define the flat norm on Cacciopoli sets? As the norm of the current corresponding to the integration of its boundary? If so then yes, you can simply take out larger and larger chunks of the set until it vanishes, thereby path-connecting it to the empty-set. It gets a bit more interesting though, if you modify the flat norm to not allow extra boundaries, then you get the homology-classes of the manifold instead.

Thanks for the response. The flat norm corresponds to integration over the set itself (not the boundary), but yes, I think taking larger chunks out is good. By contrast, the F norm  is the flat metric + the varifold metric on the measures associated to the boundary, so I think taking chunks out wouldn't be continuous?

I think the only problem with the boundary would be if you accidentally take out a whole set of positive $n-1$-dimensional measure at once. E.g. if your set is the ball $B_1(0)$ and you take out $B_s(0)$ for a parameter $s\in [0,1]$. Then this fails to be continuous at $s=1$ as original and removed boundary line up. But taking any other center for the ball works. And this should generalize, because this approach failing for every family of removed sets should imply that the boundary is not rectifiable.
